# How do I run a PowerShell script with parameters from Python

Tags: python, powershell, command-line, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run PowerShell scripts that have parameters from Python 3.7.3, but don't know how to properly call the function in Popen

What I'm trying to do with my PowerShell script is login to Cisco routers and run Cisco IOS commands on x number of routers based on how many are defined. So the way I have my PowerShell script setup I pass in the IP address of the router like `.\test.ps1 177.241.87.103` when I'm using PowerShell, or `powershell.\test.ps1 177.241.87.103` when I'm using command prompt. Both of these commands work and get the correct output and save their outputs to text files as well.

But now I want to get Python to run this "test.ps1" script with the parameter.
I've saved "test.ps1" to "C:\Users\jgreen02" and to "C:\Users\jgreen02\Desktop"

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call("powershell .\\test.ps1 177.241.87.103")
```

I'm certain I'm using the call function incorrectly, or maybe the file I'm trying to run needs to be placed in the folder where my Python script is sitting.

The error output is:

````py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jgreen02/PycharmProjects/PortChecker/Platypus.py", line 43, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["powershell test.ps1 10.238.241.38"])
  File "C:\Users\jgreen02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\jgreen02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\jgreen02\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified```
````

Comment: Make sure you're running the program in the same directory as the file.

Comment: What does this return?  

    `import os`  

    `os.getcwd()`

Comment: `subprocess.call(["powershell", "-File", ".\\test.ps1", "177.241.87.103"])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things wrong with the approach:

- [[Python.Docs]: subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

  > The arguments shown above are merely some common ones. The full function signature is the same as that of the [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor ...

  , and specifying the arguments as a sequence rather than a string is the recommended option
- When running a script, it needs to be passed via the *-File* option. For more details, check [[MS.Learn]: About PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe) (`powershell /?`)

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys


def main(*argv):
    cmd = ["PowerShell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Unrestricted", "-File", ".\\script00.ps1"]  # Specify relative or absolute path to the script
    ec = subprocess.call(cmd)
    print("Powershell returned: {:d}".format(ec))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

*script00.ps1*:

```ps1
${PSVersionTable}
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q057115405]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> Name                           Value
> ----                           -----
> PSVersion                      5.1.18362.145
> PSEdition                      Desktop
> PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
> BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.145
> CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
> WSManStackVersion              3.0
> PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
> SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
>
>
> Powershell returned: 0
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: It outputs the VersionTable in Python, but then it doesn't end the subprocess.call() function. It never prints "Powershell returned..." or "Done", I haven't altered anything that you posted. It just gets hung up on the subprocess.call(cmd) line

Comment: Then probably, the *test.exe* executable didn't end (properly). It appears it's still waiting.... And anyway, if this doesn't answer your question, you shouldn't throw yourself away to some answer that apparently solves it.